# How to change path of file from absolute to relative?

Tags: .htaccess

In my website, some of the images are having absolute path of old server *.*.*.*/old_directory/sites/, but now I have changed my server, I want that these images should be picked from /sites/ path of my current instance.

Anyone has any suggestion??

Comment: I'm afraid you need to provide more detail. Are these files manually linked from inside a Text field? Are they File fields? Have you tried changing the public file system path at admin/config/media/file-system?

Comment: These are field title's for profile fields. Configuration at admin/config/media/file-system are: Public file system path: sites/default/files, Private file system path: sites/default/files, Temporary directory: /var/tmp , Default download method: Public local files served by the webserver.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "field title's for profile fields." Pathologic (one of the answers below) works well to correct paths in fields of type "Long Text". Regarding the file system configuration: is the public path correct for your new site? (BTW the private path should not be the same as the public one)

Answer (score 1):

Install any one of the below modules.

1. [Pathlogic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic)
2. [Portable path](https://www.drupal.org/project/portable_path)